# How to execute Tornado coroutine inside of synchronous environment?

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado, future, coroutine

I have some *Tornado*'s coroutine related problem.

There is some python-model **A**, which have the abbility to execute some function. The function could be set from outside of the model. I can't change the model itself, but I can pass any function I want. I'm trying to teach it to work with Tornado's ioloop through my function, but I couldn't.

Here is the snippet:

```
import functools
import pprint
from tornado import gen
from tornado import ioloop

class A:
    f = None
    def execute(self):
      return self.f()
    pass

@gen.coroutine
def genlist():
    raise gen.Return(range(1, 10))

@gen.coroutine
def some_work():
    a = A()
    a.f = functools.partial(
        ioloop.IOLoop.instance().run_sync,
        lambda: genlist())
    print "a.f set"
    raise gen.Return(a)

@gen.coroutine
def main():
    a = yield some_work()
    retval = a.execute()
    raise gen.Return(retval)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pprint.pprint(ioloop.IOLoop.current().run_sync(main))
```

So the thing is that I set the function in one part of code, but execute it in the other part with the method of the model.

Now, Tornado 4.2.1 gave me "*IOLoop is already running*" but in Tornado 3.1.1 it works (but I don't know how exactly).

I know next things:

1. I can create new ioloop but I would like to use existent ioloop.
2. I can wrap genlist with some function which knows that genlist's result is Future, but I don't know, how to block execution until future's result will be set inside of synchronous function.

Also, I can't use result of *a.execute()* as an future object because a.execute() could be called from other parts of the code, i.e. it should return list instance.

**So, my question is**: is there any opportunity to execute asynchronous `genlist` from the synchronous model's method using current IOLoop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot restart the outer IOLoop here. You have three options:

1. Use asynchronous interfaces everywhere: change `a.execute()` and everything up to the top of the stack into coroutines. This is the usual pattern for Tornado-based applications; trying to straddle the synchronous and asynchronous worlds is difficult and it's better to stay on one side or the other.
2. Use `run_sync()` on a temporary `IOLoop`. This is what Tornado's synchronous `tornado.httpclient.HTTPClient` does, which makes it safe to call from within another `IOLoop`. However, if you do it this way the outer IOLoop remains blocked, so you have gained nothing by making `genlist` asynchronous.
3. Run `a.execute` on a separate thread and call back to the main IOLoop's thread for the inner function. If `a.execute` cannot be made asynchronous, this is the only way to avoid blocking the IOLoop while it is running.

   ```
   executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(8)

   @gen.coroutine
   def some_work():
       a = A()
       def adapter():
           # Convert the thread-unsafe tornado.concurrent.Future
           # to a thread-safe concurrent.futures.Future.
           # Note that everything including chain_future must happen
           # on the IOLoop thread.
           future = concurrent.futures.Future()
           ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_callback(
               lambda: tornado.concurrent.chain_future(
                   genlist(), future)
           return future.result()
       a.f = adapter
       print "a.f set"
       raise gen.Return(a)

   @gen.coroutine
   def main():
       a = yield some_work()
       retval = yield executor.submit(a.execute)
       raise gen.Return(retval)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Say, your function looks something like this:

```
@gen.coroutine
def foo():
    # does slow things
```

or

```
@concurrent.run_on_executor
def bar(i=1):
    # does slow things
```

You can run `foo()` like so:

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
loop = IOLoop.current()

loop.run_sync(foo)
```

You can run `bar(..)`, or any coroutine that takes args, like so:

```
from functools import partial
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

loop = IOLoop.current()

f = partial(bar, i=100)
loop.run_sync(f)
```